# File names are cut while download to folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My current code is cutting first 6 characters from file names while downloading PDF's. So for example PDF file name is `123456acII.pdf` (`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/123456acII.pdf`) but file in folder is `acII.pdf`.

How to make names be as they are?

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main = "https://example.com/"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'C:\temp\webscraping'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)


def Get_Links():
    r = requests.get(main).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    links = []
    for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-4 medium-4 columns'}):
        for n in item.find_all('a'): 
            print ('Link: '+ n.get('href'))
            links.append(n.get('href'))
    return links


def Parse_Links():
    pdf = set()
    for url in Get_Links():
        r = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'large-6 medium-8 columns large-centered'}):
            for link in item.findAll("a"):
                link = link.get("href")
                if link:
                    pdf.add(link)
    return pdf


def Save():
    for item in Parse_Links():
        print(f"Downloading File: {item[55:]}")
        filename = os.path.join(folder_location,f"{item[55:]}")
        r = requests.get(item)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    print("done")


Save()
```

Comment: try `{item[49:]}` ??

Comment: How simple was that...

Comment: Ah yes. Sometimes its the tiniest thing. Just needed another set of eyes.

Comment: Maybe you can add this as an answer. So this will be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are slicing the string starting at index position 55 `{item[55:]}`. Try to see if it's simply just starting your index position 6 positions prior:

change to: `{item[49:]}`